# Should I stop using google API V2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

I have an application for my client that uploads videos on youtube on behalf of my client.

What my client do is provide his user name and password in my app and then app uploads videos using Youtube DATA API V2(Username/password credentials).

But since username/password authentication mechanism is not available in V3, I have to change the user involvement that is required in the new Authorization mechanism. But my client is does not agree.

The question is, what if I continue to use API V2 and not switch to V3. Is there any chance that Google will stop V2 and I have to move to V3?

Is there any way I keep authenticating using credentials and not switch to OAuth 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

You asked:  `Is there any chance that google will stop V2 and I have to move to V3?`

Short answer: You need to switch to YouTube's v3 API.

From Google:

> The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March 4, 2014. Please refer to our [deprecation policy](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms#deprecation) for more information. Please use the [YouTube Data API (v3)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) for new integrations and migrate applications still using the v2 API to the v3 API as well.
>
> If you haven’t yet migrated from the previous API version (v2), we wanted to remind you it will be unsupported as of April 20, 2015, and shut down soon thereafter. To make it fast and easy for you to migrate, check out the new [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/migration-guide). It’ll help you identify the v3 API methods and parameters that correspond to the functionality that you've been using in the v2 API. It also points out new features that the v3 API supports.

[Source](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2014/09/have-you-migrated-to-data-api-v3-yet.html)

Your second question: `Is there any way I keep authenticating using credentials and not switch to OAuth 2.0?` I do not know the answer to. Maybe ask as a separate question?